# mysql comparing expression with 2 timestamps

Tags: mysql, xampp, timestamp

I am testing this command on MySQL database hosted on xampp (which is maria DB indeed). I want to compare 2 time stamps using this command:

```
SELECT * 
FROM SESSIONS 
WHERE START<='2019-08-07 11:00:00'<END 
OR START<'2019-08-07 12:00:00'<=END 
OR '2019-08-07 11:00:00'<=START<'2019-08-07 12:00:00' 
OR '2019-08-07 11:00:00'<END<='2019-08-07 12:00:00'
```

I have to use `> < =`, not `between`.

The table is class time table,
start col is the lesson starting date time, end col is the lesson end date time, when running this command the table still the same.

What is the mistake?

Comment: Basically you need to research the syntax for a fairly basic Query. [There is a manual for this](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/documentation/) SO is not a replacement for reading the manual

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your  conditions

```
  OR '2019-08-07 11:00:00'<=START<'2019-08-07 12:00:00' 
  OR '2019-08-07 11:00:00'<END<='2019-08-07 12:00:00'
```

are not valid
try using valid condition and proper format

```
SELECT * 
FROM SESSIONS 
WHERE str_to_date('2019-08-07 11:00:00', '%Y-%m-%d %T')  BETWEEN START AND END  
    OR str_to_date('2019-08-07 12:00:00', '%Y-%m-%d %T')  BETWEEN START AND END  
    OR START BETWEEN str_to_date('2019-08-07 11:00:00', '%Y-%m-%d %T') 
      AND str_to_date('2019-08-07 12:00:00', '%Y-%m-%d %T')
    OR END BETWEEN str_to_date('2019-08-07 11:00:00', '%Y-%m-%d %T') 
      AND str_to_date('2019-08-07 12:00:00', '%Y-%m-%d %T')
```

answer  updated  for use of e `=>x<=`  in this case you should use proper AND condition a group the condition using ()  eg:

so  `OR '2019-08-07 11:00:00'<=START<'2019-08-07 12:00:00'` became

```
OR ( '2019-08-07 11:00:00'<=START  AND  START <'2019-08-07 12:00:00' )
```

and       `OR '2019-08-07 11:00:00'<END<='2019-08-07 12:00:00'` became

```
OR ( '2019-08-07 11:00:00'<END  AND END  <='2019-08-07 12:00:00' )
```

Comment: But this in my case it won't give right results in alot of test cases as between is like the =>x<= and sometimes i need the >x< without equal

Comment: answer  updated ..  for valid SQL sintax  for  condition  with   `>x<`

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to use BETWEEN like this:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM SESSIONS 
WHERE ('2019-08-07 11:00:00' BETWEEN START AND END) 
  OR  ('2019-08-07 12:00:00' BETWEEN START AND END) 
  OR  ('2019-08-07 11:00:00' BETWEEN START AND END)
  OR  ('2019-08-07 11:00:00' BETWEEN START AND END)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that MySQL doesn't accept this type of expressions: `y<x<z`.

The right way is `(y<x)AND(x<z)`.